# unauthorized_client: Grant type 'authorization_code' not allowed for the client. Django -auth0 -login

Tags: python, django, authorization, auth0, unauthorized

I'm developing an app with django and when I try to use auth0 for the login I get:

```
"error": {
  "message": "Grant type 'authorization_code' not allowed for the client.",
  "oauthError": "unauthorized_client",
  "type": "oauth-authorization"
}
```

I have configured my public key and private key, the login url, and in auth0 i have configured the urls.

Additionally I notest that the mistake might be when I'm asking the access_token because i'm getting a http 403 error when i'm accessing to the auth0.com/oauth/token.

Meanwhile the server sends me this "GET /complete/auth0?redirect_state=y8oPFziJ01BmdGaRbsRJZod3GZ4dP0hW HTTP/1.1" 500 116725

Answer (score 17):

I got the same issue, and I found I had to grant more permission using the Advanced setting on the Application page  (Grant Type tab):

[image]