# Flutter Auth0 Login Fail to get to web login due to Unauthroized

Tags: flutter, auth0

**Hey Fellow Developers,**

I am working on a flutter application and I am currently implementing Auth0. However when I am sending a web authentication login request it fails due to not being authorized.

Here is the login code

```
final auth0 = Auth0(
  'DOMAIN Goes Here',
  'Client ID Goes Here',
);
final result = await auth0.webAuthentication().login(redirectUrl: 'URL Redirection Here');
```

Here is the Error log via Auth0
[image: Error Log Via Auth0]

Here is a further look at the error
[image: Further Error Log]

I have the ability to get a Token to send with the login however there is no option to add it because usually you would get a token after you login.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

======UPDATE=======

I changed some settings within auth0 that was suggested via a comment now when the application runs and login is pressed it sends the user to an empty browser and no error message.

[image: Image showing new problem]

Cheers Devs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was the emulator. When I switched from the emulator to a real device the Auth0 worked perfect.

Comment: Did you find any solution to use the emulator?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We decided to move away from auth0 as we couldn't get it to run how we needed it.

Comment: sad to hear that, we finally make it work as we expected, I think the need to upgrade a lot the documentation, but didn't make it work on emulator so we are working all of the time with real devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add authorization_code to the auth0 (typically this is a token or something like that)also try to send your request in postman it really helps

Comment: also i found similar question hope this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984893/unauthorized-client-grant-type-authorization-code-not-allowed-for-the-client

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. I added the extra permissions within the settings now I am just getting a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I added the audience URL to the login function. I also changed Emulator for testing.